# Safari 4 starting up slowly on a Vista machine

Tags: windows-vista, boot, safari, performance

I have two PCs (different specs) with the latest Windows Vista and Safari 4 updates installed. In one machine, Safari 4 works great but in the other, it starts up slowly (less than a minute though) with harddisk sound indicating data access activities.

I have cleared all internet caches and I am quite sure that there is no virus in both machines. Are there any other reasons that Safari performances are so different in comparably similar software and hardware environments?

Comment: I think using safari on windows is a sin.

Comment: Honestly, Apple is terrible at programming on Windows most of the time (please learn about multithreading itunes...). Your problem could be a marketing issue, "See how crappy Safari runs on your PC? You should be using a Mac."

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I haven't solved this problem. And I cannot reproduce the symptom since I formatted and reinstalled Windows Vista (for other causes).

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your computer and install Safari 5.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have too much addons installed?

Comment: No, I don't even know if there is an add-on for Safari 4 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall and reinstall Safari using [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

If this is still happening, I would use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see why the disk is churning, comparing this with the other PC where it starts faster.

If this also doesn't show anything, one would have to chalk it up to differences between the two PCs, such as faster or less-fragmented disk, fragmented registry, or other causes.